# jQuery on.('click') don't trigger or don't get .text at first click

Tags: jquery

I would like to get text value of a clicked element and I encoutered two problems.

The first is that I can't get a click event stated a node. I mean I have this HTML:

```
<div id="option-panel" class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="tab-content tab-content-options" id="pills-tabContent"><div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="pills-gamme" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-gamme-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills range-selector mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="pill no-anim active" id="pills-Duel-tab" data-toggle="pill" data-ar="ARXXXXXXXXXXX1" href="#pills-Duel" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-Duel" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <span>Duel</span>
                <img src="#">
            </a>
            <span class="price">+ 100 €</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="pill no-anim" id="pills-Prime-tab" data-toggle="pill" data-ar="ARXXXXXXXXXXX2" href="#pills-Prime" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-Prime" aria-selected="true">
                <span>Prime</span>
                <img src="#">
            </a>
            <span class="price">+ 120 €</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$('#option-panel').on('click', function() {...} // is WORKING
$('#option-panel .range-selector li').on('click', function() {..} isn't working
```

How is it possible ? Do you have an idea ?

So I decided to bypass this issue and try to get the text value of the span.price of the click (and active) pills.

with this JS:

```
function updateRecap() {
let price = '';
let label = '';
$('#option-panel').on('click', function() {

    price = $(this).find('.pill.active + .price').text();
    label = $(this).find('.pill.active span').text();
    
    let value = label + '(' + price + ')';

    $('.value-gamme').text(value);
  });
```

}

It's worked but just after the second click.. This first is empty when I console.log. Or put in try to put in the DOM.

I make a short video of the behaviour if it's can help.

[Download the video from WeTransfert.com](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/06f6c4d0d1b1e12f919ea6c7f97193ba20200810151028/0374c8cf4a2be8f1ac6286fd50ba992020200810151118/7db81f)

Comment: In the video you can see the content appear a the first line of the table (on the right, the content is toggling in green)

Comment: There is no element with `class="li"` in the HTML. Did you mean the `li` elements themselves? If so the selector should be `$('#option-panel .range-selector li').on(...`, note the `.` is removed

Comment: Oh the it's a mistake when I copy the code in the question ^^

Comment: Either @RoryMcCrossan is right or you have something that prevents you to reach the element for example a parent listener destroying your click event or an element that is virtually over your clicked area which intercepts your event

Comment: "*a mistake when I copy the code*" - can you update the mistake?

Comment: "*This first is empty when I console.log*" - where is your console.log?  It's unusual to add a click handler like that inside another method rather than just in doc ready - so this implies that your console.log may be outside the click handler

Comment: Both click handlers can be seen to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/nqutj7mf/ - please review [mcve] and provided a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) that *demonstrates* the problem - the html and code (copy mistake not withstanding) *as provided* work perfectly fine.

Comment: @freedomn-mv sure :)

Comment: the function is declared before I fire all the function I need in a document.ready. 

It's a job I made inside a Prestashop plugin, before that I made a prototype (only HTML, sass, bootstrap and jQ and it's work), So I guess it's useless to reproduce in a JS fiddle.

I guss you're right, another JS is maybe destroying the click event or HTML element overlaping the content I need to trigger.

I will check this today

Comment: @DiegoCavalletti Some of my "final" HTML il created by othres functions (I read a JSON and have some forEach to create the layout with templates literals.. Do you think that is probably the key of the problem ? I don't know how I can check if this make some issues..

Comment: @LucasJ i was actually speaking of CSS issues, where you have some element overlapping and one of them (higher zindex for example) intercepts and block your listener. It's not so easy to say what's the problem with your example. If i copy-paste your code in my editor i see that there are some closing tag missing, have u checked that?

Comment: @DiegoCavalletti I just checked and no closing tag missing, I forget some closing tag (I fixed the missing </div>) because I cutted the HTML to put in my question (because the original HTML is much longer and it was the end of my day ahah so tired). 

I will specify maximum of HTML element with a good Z-index and see if it's work. 

But when I use #option-panel tu fire the click event, and make some trick to get the data I need, I have a second strange behaviour, the first click get nothing, the second get the good value. And it's this for all the next click .. Never get this before :(

Comment: @LucasJ i suggest you use codepen (https://codepen.io/) or any other code website to paste a working copy of what u've done so that we can all watch into that and point you into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

@DiegoCavalletti I tried to add an onclick="", so I can trigger the event as I want (I assumed is less cleaner but.. ).

But something is wierd, console.log($(this)); give me:

```
m.fn.init [Window]
0: Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 2, frames: Window, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)
```

what does it mean ? I hoped get an HTML element but no..

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the problem.

My app is a collection of HTML containers (empty). I have sereval function where I browse a JSON to create all repeated element (list, tabs, etc...).

I don't encored this issues with the firsts functions. So I split all the functions who "Create and fill the layout" in the document.ready() with the functions "who manage the user interactions" in $(window).load(function() I juste created.

So everything works. Thanks to all, you helped me in the search of the problem :) Especially @DiegoCavalletti ;)

Below a part of the problem solved:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    createStepper(); // create stepper to browse the app
    createTabPane(); // create some tabs needed for a part of the app

    $.getJSON('URL_OF_JSON', function (jsonArray) {
        allProduct = jsonArray;
        content = '';
        createRange(); // Fill a tab with content (template literals + JSON)
        createRecap();   // Fill a DIV with a table who related step create in createStepper
    });
});

$(window).load(function() {
    updateTitle(); // function to update title page move thanks to the stepper
    updateRecap(); // function to listen event click and update content
});
```

So the app is loaded and after, the functions which interact with the app are called.